# Unknown action, even if I used collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, routes, action

Rails 2.2.3, Ruby 1.8.7

I have a controller Forms. There are many forms... I declared methode import_cash_payments on controller forms, after I added it in routes via collection. Anyway, It's give me this error.

**Look, that's in my forms_controller.rb:**

```
def import_cash_payments
      @title = "Импорт наличных оплат"
end
```

**That's routes:**

```
map.resources :forms,
    :collection => {
      :import_cash_payments => :post, {...}, :export_form10 => :post
    }
```

Also, I have view file: forms/import_cash_payments.html.erb

**This I recive:(view)**

```
Unknown action
No action responded to show. Actions: ...(many actions)..., import_cash_payments, ...(many actions)...
```

**That's from rake routes command in console:**

```
 import_cash_payments_forms POST   /forms/import_cash_payments                         {:controller=>"forms", :action=>"import_cash_payments"}
```

Comment: How does your view look?

Comment: I marked it in post as "This I recive".

Answer (score 1):

In rails 3 and 4

```
# config/routes.rb
. . .
resources :forms do
  collection do
    post 'import_cash_payments'
  end
end
. . .
# controllers/forms_controller.rb
class FormsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @cash = Cash.new
  end

  def import_cash_paymenes
    @cash = Cash.new(cash_params)
    @cash.save
    . . .
  end
end

# app/views/forms/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @cash, url: 'import_cash_payments_path' do %>
. . .
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I use Rails 2.2.3.